Which extension ring for stucco?
I installed single gang boxes for my exterior wall: https://www.homedepot.com/pep/202077343
My stucco contractor said all of these boxes are not deep enough and he needs an extension ring to bring the box out to the border of the finished stucco.
He installed these:

They feel pretty tiny and flimsy to me. You can also see while the box in the back is fairly large, the opening of this ring is pretty small so I’m afraid pulling wires through the ENT tubes and folding back/forth wires will be a big pain.
Are these the right boxes or can they at least be reasonably used?
If no, what are the right extension rings needed?

it seem like you only need about half an inch, Are theses rings approved to be trimmed to a reduced depth?

Not sure. I think it’s a bit more than 1/2” though
